# ngbootstrap carousel not working as expected

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Right now I am working on a basic website where I require a carousel. Tried with bootstrap carousel but found that on clicking prev/next icon, angular router kicks in and navigates to home url (as routed to home component when invalid url encounters). Did a bit of study and came across ng-bootstrap carousel. Added the same into my project. However, carousel is not working as expected.

I had material added in that project. Thinking this might have effected this, hence this time created a whole new test project. Copied the first carousel example
from here https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples
But the output is same as earlier.
[image: Refer to this image]

Tried adding localize polyfill as well after that. Still no change. Unable to figure out what is the issue and what's the way around.

**my package.json:**

```json
{
   "name":"test-carousel",
   "version":"0.0.0",
   "scripts":{
      "ng":"ng",
      "start":"ng serve",
      "build":"ng build",
      "watch":"ng build --watch --configuration development",
      "test":"ng test"
   },
   "private":true,
   "dependencies":{
      "@angular/animations":"~12.2.0",
      "@angular/common":"~12.2.0",
      "@angular/compiler":"~12.2.0",
      "@angular/core":"~12.2.0",
      "@angular/forms":"~12.2.0",
      "@angular/localize":"~12.2.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser":"~12.2.0",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":"~12.2.0",
      "@angular/router":"~12.2.0",
      "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap":"^10.0.0",
      "bootstrap":"^5.1.3",
      "rxjs":"~6.6.0",
      "tslib":"^2.3.0",
      "zone.js":"~0.11.4"
   },
   "devDependencies":{
      "@angular-devkit/build-angular":"~12.2.4",
      "@angular/cli":"~12.2.4",
      "@angular/compiler-cli":"~12.2.0",
      "@types/jasmine":"~3.8.0",
      "@types/node":"^12.11.1",
      "jasmine-core":"~3.8.0",
      "karma":"~6.3.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher":"~3.1.0",
      "karma-coverage":"~2.0.3",
      "karma-jasmine":"~4.0.0",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter":"~1.7.0",
      "typescript":"~4.3.5"
   }
}
```

**my angular.json:**

```json
{
   "$schema":"./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
   "version":1,
   "newProjectRoot":"projects",
   "projects":{
      "test-carousel":{
         "projectType":"application",
         "schematics":{
            "@schematics/angular:application":{
               "strict":true
            }
         },
         "root":"",
         "sourceRoot":"src",
         "prefix":"app",
         "architect":{
            "build":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
               "options":{
                  "outputPath":"dist/test-carousel",
                  "index":"src/index.html",
                  "main":"src/main.ts",
                  "polyfills":"src/polyfills.ts",
                  "tsConfig":"tsconfig.app.json",
                  "assets":[
                     "src/favicon.ico",
                     "src/assets"
                  ],
                  "styles":[
                     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                     "src/styles.css"
                  ],
                  "scripts":[
                     
                  ]
               },
               "configurations":{
                  "production":{
                     "budgets":[
                        {
                           "type":"initial",
                           "maximumWarning":"500kb",
                           "maximumError":"1mb"
                        },
                        {
                           "type":"anyComponentStyle",
                           "maximumWarning":"2kb",
                           "maximumError":"4kb"
                        }
                     ],
                     "fileReplacements":[
                        {
                           "replace":"src/environments/environment.ts",
                           "with":"src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                        }
                     ],
                     "outputHashing":"all"
                  },
                  "development":{
                     "buildOptimizer":false,
                     "optimization":false,
                     "vendorChunk":true,
                     "extractLicenses":false,
                     "sourceMap":true,
                     "namedChunks":true
                  }
               },
               "defaultConfiguration":"production"
            },
            "serve":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
               "configurations":{
                  "production":{
                     "browserTarget":"test-carousel:build:production"
                  },
                  "development":{
                     "browserTarget":"test-carousel:build:development"
                  }
               },
               "defaultConfiguration":"development"
            },
            "extract-i18n":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
               "options":{
                  "browserTarget":"test-carousel:build"
               }
            },
            "test":{
               "builder":"@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
               "options":{
                  "main":"src/test.ts",
                  "polyfills":"src/polyfills.ts",
                  "tsConfig":"tsconfig.spec.json",
                  "karmaConfig":"karma.conf.js",
                  "assets":[
                     "src/favicon.ico",
                     "src/assets"
                  ],
                  "styles":[
                     "src/styles.css"
                  ],
                  "scripts":[
                     
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "defaultProject":"test-carousel"
}
```

**app.module.ts:**

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
    @NgModule({
    declarations: [
     AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      NgbModule
     ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your developer console?

Comment: @kottartillsalu nope not at all

Comment: Ng-bootstrap 10 is not compatible with bootstrap 5+. You'd need to use the ng-boostrap  v11 beta or downgrade to bootstrap 4.6.x

Comment: @kottartillsalu it worked! Thanks. I relied too much on npm thinking it would install accurate version.